# Wrong Output: Wrapped Matrix Wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, conways-game-of-life

Trying to get the matrices to wrap around itself using modulus.

```
def neighbors(inputArray, row, col):
    count = 0
    for x, y in ((row - 1, col), (row + 1, col), (row, col - 1), (row, col + 1), (row - 1, col - 1), (row - 1, col + 1), (row + 1, col - 1), (row + 1, col + 1)):
        if not (0 <= x < len(inputArray) and 0 <= y < len(inputArray[x])):
            continue
        if inputArray[x][y] == "O":
            count += 1
    return count
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use modular arithmetic for the wrap-around. If you use modular arithmetic on the indices throughout then there is no need to treat the edge cells any differently. For example, use `(row + 1) % n` rather than just `row + 1` (where `n` is the number of columns).

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, you should try to add a minimum content. In this case, you should show your input and output, what did you try and any research...

Answer (score 0):

'%' is the modulo operator in python. See the reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

For your code, the fix would be to remove the first if that is checking if the (x, y) is valid and just do

```
 if inputArray[x % len(inputArray)][y % len(inputArray[0])]:
     count += 1
```